# How to create a cron task in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, cron, cron-task

I have a little question, how create a simple cron task who call some service action in Symfony, who could be executed automatically each night ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Symfony2 does not manage cron tasks, simply because this is system level. That being said, you can [create a command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) and register it as a cron task.

Comment: Just found this thread on Google. Old, but here is a post just about this subject: https://inuits.eu/blog/creating-automated-interval-based-cron-tasks-symfony2. I found it very handy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CommandSchedulerBundle](https://github.com/J-Mose/CommandSchedulerBundle)

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [TaskScheduleBundle](https://github.com/Rewieer/TaskSchedulerBundle) to make your cron jobs within symfony.